# Interactive sorting requires two hits to work

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

A small annoyance which is hopefully easily solved.

I've got a simple SSRS tablix with interactive sorting on the first column which is also the only group in the report and made up of strings.

I've added interactive sorting to this column like so:

[image]

Initially when the report is rendered it is sorted alphabetically; this is done via the sorting property of the Group `RepOperName`.

Why when I look at report in the web portal when I hit this interactive button the first time nothing happens i.e it is originally sorted A-Z and it stays sorted A-Z; only when I hit it the second time does it become sorted Z-A - how do I get around this so that it goes Z-A the first time I hit the interactive button?

Comment: Have you tried setting the sorting at the tablix level to be `[RepOperName]`? I'm curious if this fixes it.

Comment: nope - doesn't seem to work; do you encounter the same problem? it's almost as if it is in a neutral state before hitting the interactive sort button then another push of the button is required for it to change the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a bit tricky - sorting works fine, the problem is, that by default, interactive sorting always sorts records in ascending order first. After second 'hit', it sorts descending. Bad news is, that this behavior cannot be changed. Partially good news is, that you can change the source field for sorting to have different order, but for text column, it may hit performance. Here's the link that shows possible workarounds.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/Daniel/ssas/1820/ssrs-change-the-interactive-sort-default-to-descending

Second solution, but not so elegant, would be applying descending order by default in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marek- I used the workaround in the BIDN blog; no noticeable performance loss and works perfectly